# Is it possible to type a floating "c" letter?

Tags: text-editing

I have a close friend that has a Scottish surname "McGregor". However the "c" in the name needs to be aligned to the top of the "M". I have searched through alt codes but cannot spot it anywhere. Does anyone know if this is even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing this in a basic "text editor"  such as Notepad or similar (or most standard programs, where this is simply treated as a standard "c" character) is not too easy and I believe could be done using non-standard unicode characters, though this is messy and within a program that does not support unicode all you will see is a "box".

As an example, MᶜGregor would be a unicode equivalent (U+1D9C in the Windows 7 Character Map tool), but if you are using a program that can sort by name this will most likely be sorted into the wrong place.  This also depends on the font you are using having that character available, Arial and Calibri have it available, but not all fonts will and Cambria is a font that does not.

Within a real word processing application program such as Microsoft Word or OpenOffice this is relatively easy, select the "c" character, right click, look for a "font properties" type option and in that properties window look for a "superscript" option.  This will make the "c" float in the way you are wanting, but only within that document.

Comment: So the solution is simple if *markup* can be used.